# What is causing the ticket system to not function?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, ticket-system

sorry that this is probably rather easy to fix (I don't really understand the docs)
But, I want a channel to be opened, so only the user and mods can see it. It will be opened when the user adds a reaction to the message, the reaction will then be deleted (leaving just the bot's reaction)
Currently, my code is:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            if user.channel.id == 850622999577231370:
                await message.remove_reaction("", user)
                overwrites = {
                    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
                }
                n = random.randomint(1, 1000)
                await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {n}', overwrites=overwrites, categoty="Tickets")
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
```

It doesn't seem to run, since there is no error message, but no channels are created either

Comment: Have you used `print` statements to see where the bot gets stuck?

Comment: @Dominik Used them, it just isn’t running at all.

Comment: What is `if user.channel.id` supposed to do? I have never seen anything like this. `if reaction.channel.id` makes more sense.

Comment: It’s stuff I found on other posts tied together

Comment: Where did you define `guild`?

Comment: Make sure the message is actually in the bots cache, you can do this by sending a message *once* the bot is online, use `on_raw_reaction_add` if you don't need the cached message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

- `random.randomint` does not exist, it must be `random.randrange`.
- You didn't define `guild` in the provided code, we'll just use `user.guild` instead.
- To get the channel we use `if reaction.message.channel.id` and not `if user.channel.id`, that makes little sense here.

**Here is a possible new code:**

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji == '':
        print("Reaction")
        if reaction.message.channel.id == Your_Channel_ID:
            await reaction.message.remove_reaction("", user)
            guild = user.guild # We get the guild
            overwrites = {
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
            }
            n = random.randrange(1, 1000) # We choose a number from randrange 1-1000
            await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket {n}', overwrites=overwrites, categoty="Tickets")
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Great, I’ll look at it when I’m next working. Randomint was defined earlier by importing something, but I prefer your way